# Publishing Fantasy versus Realistic Fiction (multiple questions)

Tags: publishing, fantasy

So, I have a few questions that I'll address in a short little list. I figure it's best to include them all in one rather than dumping several questions on you guys, since they all relate.

Here goes:

**1) When attempting to publish a fantasy book, how do I want to select a publisher? Is it possible to find a list of publishers that publish specifically fantasy books?**

**2) Similar to #1, but for agents. Are some agents specifically geared towards fantasy books?**

**3) Similar to #1 and #2, but for editors that don't work for the publishers. Does this matter? Should I only go with a "fantasy" editor?**

**4) Am I right in assuming that a fantasy book will garner much less interest than a realistic fiction novel?** On one hand, fantasy has its own market of readers that are always looking for new, great fantasy books... and on the other hand, realistic fiction is much more widely read than fantasy books (obviously with some exceptions within the genre).

**5) What are some good resources for writing fantasy? Things to consider, things to do or not do?** I realize this question might be vague, but I wonder if you guys might be able to share some good links to some reading, or even books on the topic. I'm not asking for a list of everything possible, but any advice or resources you can share.

Thanks guys!

Comment: @Aerodynamo - please edit this to be just question 1, then ask your other questions as separate questions.  It'll be clearer, more focused, and better that way.

Comment: Seconded - these are great questions, but the Q&A format works much much better if we can focus on a single question at a time. Possibly questions 1-3 can be combined into a single question - people will have comments about the entire publishing process as well - but the other two would be better off separate.

Comment: I agree. And it'd be a way for us to have more questions on the site. =P

Comment: Shelved by request until decision is reached about what to do with question. See: http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/310/what-is-the-official-line-on-mega-questions for details.

Comment: Voted to close as not being a real question. Clean up that mess.

Comment: I have to close so the author can re-post as separate questions. A big part of this site is the vetting (voting) of the answers and this solicits many answers in a single post. It's necessary that questions contain a specific, detailed, answerable question. (1)(2)(3) could conceivably be combined into one useful question. (4) is at least somewhat answerable if you're looking for readership statistics. (5) Is way too broad; Asking for a list of resources isn't really what we do here. A list of "things to consider" would be nebulous. Better to ask *specific* problems you are trying to solve.

Comment: Hey guys, I will repost. I thought it would be easier to list it out in one question, because I thought it would be spam to put up a ton of questions. Thanks guys! I'll repost this later today.